# Facebook Graph API: What's the purpose of the distinction between "links" and "statuses" resp. "read_stream" and "friends_status" permissions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am building a feature that is using the shared links of a facebook user's friends as input.

Looking for the best way to obtain all those links I stumbled upon the following problem:

Shared links are represented in the Graph API by either objects of type *[link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/link/)* or of type *[status](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/status/)* (where the message contains a link).

What I am confused about is that in order to obtain those links different permissions are required: read_stream (which is quite obtrusive) for the former and friends_status for the latter.

Does this make any sense? Isn't *statuses* a super-set of *links*? Or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `friends_status` unless you plan on reading the user's friends' statuses for links. You only need to ask for the `read_stream` permission. This will let you read anything on the user's wall, even if it was posted by a friend.

Comment: Yea, I know... I was hoping that the less obstrusive `friends_status` would suffice since all I am interested in is the links of a user's friends and not everything that is in that user's stream.

Comment: Use `friends_status` in that case, as the `read_stream` would provide more junk data. `read_stream` won't let you look at Friends' posts anyway.

Comment: Are you saying I can get the User object's `links` connections without the `read_stream` permission? Because afaik `links` and `statuses` connections don't overlap and I need `read_stream` for the `links`.

Comment: From what you've told me, you are only interested in Links the user's friends share, so you don't need `read_stream`, since there is no need to look at the user's stream. However, if want to read the user's stream for links posted by friends, then you will need both permissions.

Comment: Thanks for your answers but I am still confused. I cannot access the shared links of a user's friends without the `read_stream` permission. If I only use `friends_status` the response for `http://graph.facebook.com/A_FRIEND/links`will be empty.

Comment: Then it must mean you need to use both permissions, even if it means users won't be happy.

Comment: I wonder if there's a definitive and comprehensive article about this somewhere... The FB Graph API doc/guide doesn't seem very helpful.